# connecting to socket using asynctask android

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

I'm trying to make a splashscreen while it appears I'm trying to connect the server through socket.

I'm pretty new to Android business so there is a chance I made it wrong, anyway it does not work.

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
private Socket socket; // the socket
private final int port = 1500; // the socket port - 1500
private boolean connectivity=false; // if connected to the socket or not
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    ConnectToServer cts= new ConnectToServer();
    cts.execute();}


private class ConnectToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

 @Override
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
     try {
         Log.d("socket", "trying to connect");
         socket = new Socket("10.0.0.11", port);
     } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e1.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e1) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e1.printStackTrace();
     }
     if (socket.isConnected())
         connectivity=true;
     return null;
 }}


 protected void onPostExecute() {
// execution of result of Long time consuming operation
 Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("connectivity", connectivity);
 startActivity(i);
 finish();}
```

Comment: Are you trying this on emulator or real device? cuz on emu it wont work

Comment: on real device of course

Comment: Im afraid that 10.0.0.11 (which is a LAN IP) is unreachable for android since its not a part of your LAN. Android has its own virtual LAN and its own 127.0.0.1/localhost and thus request to 10.x.x.x IPs wont leave an AOS. Such packets gonna die inside AOS

Comment: Before I decided to use asynctask , i wrote this code in a different way using a simple thread.
that ip address works great and i was able to connect my Server , so this is not the problem.

the problem is - with this kind of code (AsyncTask) I can not connect to the server, basically nothing happens with this code

Comment: and? does it worked for you? If it does, just try to fallback to simple thread simetimes it works better and faster than AsyncTask so there was no point to make AsyncTask. Also make sure Wifi is turned on. :) Also did you see the log msg from `Log.d("socket", "trying to connect");`?

Comment: no i don't get this msg , which makes me think he never went into this code , maybe there's a problem in the use of the AsyncTask. maybe i wrote it wrong ot not using it as well.

Comment: And is there no any exceptions so far in logcat? And my suggestions about LAN are applicable to emu only, I was wrong.

Comment: i also got the impression that more right to do that way than just a simple thread. for that kind of thing as connecting Socket This class exists at all

Comment: there are not any exceptions in logcat , it's just doing nothing from the moment i'm running the application. (this is the first activity)

Comment: I don't think an Asynctask could be useful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG! you had misplaced a curly bracket!!! Also I suggest you to make those properties protected instead of private its a long story to explain why (its to prevent to create special static methods to be able to get your private fields. you cant see that process which is done by a compiler).

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    protected Socket socket; // the socket
    protected final int port = 1500; // the socket port - 1500
    protected boolean connectivity=false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    ConnectToServer cts= new ConnectToServer();
    cts.execute();
    }

    private class ConnectToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

         @Override
         protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

             Log.d("socket", "trying to connect");
             try {
                 socket = new Socket("10.0.0.11", port);
             } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e1.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IOException e1) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e1.printStackTrace();
             }
             if (socket.isConnected())
                 connectivity=true;
             return null;
         } // here u have the second } and you finished the class declaration without the following method which is overriden in activity!!!


          @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
         Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PreviewActivity.class);
         i.putExtra("connectivity", connectivity);
         startActivity(i);
         finish();

         }
    }
}
```

Comment: but ofcourse it compiles good! The Activity has its own `protected void onPostExecute()` method but you need to override it in the AsyncTask class declaration!!!! Not the activity's one!!!!

Comment: I have updated the src, just copypaste it if you still don't get the point.

Comment: Wow I did not even notice I'll try now

Comment: I had inserted your code in my project and it works, at least it dumps the log message. be careful about curly brackets.

Comment: I had updated the code, the onPostExecute was inproperly declared/overriden so if you really took my code it should not compile.

Comment: i also add the @Override line , but i still dont gey anything
even the msg : "trying to connect"

Comment: and yes i will be more careful about curly brackets . thanks about that

Comment: ok i get the msg :  "trying to connect" .
but there is'nt connection with the socket...

Comment: Well, at my side the onPostExecute(Void result) trigged only when I commented the try block of doInBackground(); So I cant tell you whats wrong with your socket now But Im sure AsyncTask is OK now. And you are wellcome but you need to accept my answer :) here it works so