# AsyncTask - Modifier not allowed here

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to follow the [example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in the official Android Development page to create an AsyncTask class, however I keep getting this error:

**Error:(13, 9) error: modifier private not allowed here**

Here you can find my code:

```
package aloha.com.ar.dummy;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;


private class Connection extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, Void > {

 protected String doInBackground() {
  try {
   BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

   Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 10023);
   DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
   BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
   outToServer.writeBytes("Hello from Java!");
   // Answer = inFromServer.readLine();
   // System.out.println(modifiedSentence);
   clientSocket.close();
   return "Connected";

  } catch (Exception e) {
   return e.toString();
  }
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate() {}

 protected void onPostExecute() {}
}
```

Comment: it should be `public class Connection`

Comment: Changing to Public:
Error:(13, 8) error: Connection is not abstract and does not override abstract method doInBackground(Void...) in AsyncTask

Comment: yup , you have the wrong implementation of methods like `doInBackground` and others , use `ctrl+space` to override the appropriate methods plus read the complete docs

Comment: @PavneetSingh I just copied the example from the development guide :-(
ctrl+space doesn't solve it. Could you help me by posting the answer? Thanks!

Comment: try this example , very much close to what your want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036007/connecting-to-socket-using-asynctask-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to extend AsyncTask with correct generic types, AsyncTask takes 3 of them, params that you pass to doInBackground, param you pass to publishProgress and param for result, thats why you are getting error class have to be delcared abstract.

Comment: Thanks, but if I declare it as abstract, then I cannot instantiated right? How can I call execute then?

Comment: If you are willing to use it, you shouldnt make it abstract. Make your method like that protected Void doInBackgroud(Void... params) and it should be fine

Answer (score -1):

You can't call private class in another class, it must be public or package private(without modifier)

Comment: Changing to Public: Error:(13, 8) error: Connection is not abstract and does not override abstract method doInBackground(Void...) in AsyncTask